# pytest: session_transaction did not enter the condition

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, session

I try to write unit test and then I found this problem because I want to check if there is a `session`.

```
def get_session():
    if "test" in session:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

this is my method and this is in my test_login.py

```
def test_get_session(client):
    with client.session_transaction() as session:
        session["test"] = "testttt"
    result = get_session()
    assert "test" in session
    assert result == 1
```

I think the result should be 1 but when I run pietist

```
________________________________ test_get_session _________________________________

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'app'>>

    def test_get_session(client):
        with client.session_transaction() as session:
            session["test"] = "testttt"
        result = get_session()
        assert "test" in session
>       assert result == 1
E       assert 2 == 1

test_login.py:54: AssertionError
```

I wonder why `assert "test" in session` is passed but it enter `else`.
I want to test functionality in `if`.
Or is there another way you can recommend for me to test the session?

Answer (score 0):

```
def test_get_session(client):
    with client.session_transaction() as session:
        session["test"] = "testttt"
    result = get_session()
    assert "test" in session  # This assertion is correct; it checks if "test" is in the session
    assert result == 1  # This assertion fails, indicating that result is 2, not 1
```

The second assertion fails because the get_session method returns 2 instead of 1, as anticipated, when "test" is in the session. To correct this, edit your test case so that it appropriately asserts the intended behavior of your get_session function:

```
def test_get_session(client):
    with client.session_transaction() as session:
        session["test"] = "testttt"
    result = get_session()
    assert result == 1  # Check if the function returns 1 when "test" is in the session
    assert "test" in session  # Check if "test" is in the session
```